# Does a commentator benefit from comment upvotes?

Tags: support, comments, voting

What is comment upvoting for and what does the commentator get when his comments get upvoted?

Comment: @user178049 I don't know that a [commentator](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/commentator "a person who makes commentaries") is the same thing as a [commenter](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commenter "One who makes or writes comments") . I know there was a misspelling in the title, so your edit is an improvement, it's just when I read "commentator" I think of Howard Cosell :)

Comment: @ColleenV There was a discussion on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/difference-between-commentor-and-commentator). If I actually understand the top-voted answer, I think it should be fine. I thought of using "comment author"; I guess it's a bit too long for a title :).

Comment: @user178049 Well, that question and answer is almost 8 years old - that seems like a very long time for a word that is primarily Internet related, like "commenter". [Oxford has a nice definition of commenter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commenter) now: "A person who expresses an opinion or engages in discussion of an issue or event, especially online in response to an article or blog post." I thought this article expressed the difference pretty well too: https://jakubmarian.com/difference-between-commenter-and-commentator/

Answer (score 2):

Comment up-voting is to indicate that you agree with or like the comment. It doesn't give the author of the comment any benefit except to count toward [the Pundit badge](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit). Its primary purpose it to give people a way to voice their opinion without having to add a duplicate or "Me too!" comment.

The [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) has [more information about commenting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Let's say I aked a question and someone wrote a comment on it and the comment helped me with the question, would it be ok if I upvote the comment?

Comment: If the comment helped you, you definitely should up-vote it instead of commenting "Thanks!" - Up-votes are the preferred way to say "thank you" on StackExchange :)